# Weird characters when using cursive SelectView

Tags: rust, ncurses, tui

Here is my code:

```
extern crate cursive;

use cursive::Cursive;
use cursive::views::{SelectView, Dialog};
use cursive::align::HAlign;

fn main() {
    let mut time_select = SelectView::new().h_align(HAlign::Center);
    time_select.add_item("Short", 1);
    time_select.add_item("Medium", 5);
    time_select.add_item("Long", 10);

    let mut siv = Cursive::new();
    siv.add_layer(Dialog::around(time_select).title("How long is your wait?"));
    siv.run();
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

This happens with multiple terminal emulators. How can I solve this?

Comment: Cursive expects UTF-8 output. What is set to the `$LANG` of your terminal?

Comment: I'm using en_GB.UTF-8, also other utf-8 characters work.

Comment: It works for me in pterm and gnome-terminal.  I also suspect your terminal isn't really UTF-8; I can get a similar effect if I change my terminal encoding to something non-UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me when editing through `vim`, running it this way solved it:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 cargo run
```

This should work if you're using `bash` or another shell that supports setting the environment this way.